# Use Binding to set rowheight of DataGrid instead of SharedSizeGroup?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to develop a datagrid which contains a Grid as Celltemplate in Column A (light blueSee picture) and another Grid as CellTemplate in Column B (dark blue). I wan't to achive that the height of the first and the last row in the two grids have the same heigt. I tried to do this, by using SharedSizeGroups, which worked. However, this has the downside, that row 3 of the Grid has always the height of the larges row 3 in all grids (well, thats what SharedSizeGroups do, so not much surprise there).

As you can see in the example, I would like to set the height of row 3 in the grid depending on the number of detailrecords (light blue = dark blue frame).

Is it possible, to bind the height of row 3 in the right grid (dark blue) to the height of row 3 in the left grid? Please keep in mind, that the parent to both grids is a datagrid, which makes binding by name not possible (at least i assume).

The xaml is quiet extensive, but I would be happy to post it, if that helps

[image]